# Testing a button click in React Native with Jest and enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am new to testing react native apps with Jest and have no idea what i am doing. I have done some research online but most of the courses seem to be outdated.

I have an image within my app that when pressed takes the user to another screen. After doing some research it seems that using enzyme is the way to do this (this is most likely outdated and I am doing it wrong).

Here is my code.

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import HomeScreen, { TouchableOpacity } from '../app/HomeScreen';
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-native-testing-library';
import { configure, shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

it("can press the button", () => {
  
const onPressMock = jest.fn();

const button = shallow((<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressMock} />));
button.find('button').simulate('click');
expect(onPressMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(onPressMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

When I run my test with yarn I get the following error, is there any way to fix this?

[image: error]

Here is the code my HomeScreen

```js
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component 
{
 render() {
   
  return (
  <ScrollView>
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Listen')}>
     <ImageBackground source={require('./bible.png')} style={{width: '100%', opacity: 0.8}}>
              <Text style={styles.MainText}>Sermons</Text>
              </ImageBackground>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Events')}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('./events.png')} style={{width: '100%', opacity: 0.8}}>
              <Text style={styles.MainText}>Events</Text>
         </ImageBackground>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Connect')}>
         <ImageBackground source={require('./connect.png')} style={{width: '100%', opacity: 0.8}}>
              <Text style={styles.MainText}>Connect</Text>
         </ImageBackground>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About')}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('./church.png')} style={{width: '100%', opacity: 0.8}}>
              <Text style={styles.MainText}>About</Text>
         </ImageBackground>
         </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>

    </ScrollView>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: It seems that, at some point, you are setting a `contextTypes` property in `TouchableOpacity` component. Can you show the relevant code of the component?

Comment: I have added it to my question

Comment: It seems that in your test you are testing the `TouchableOpacity` component in `../app/HomeScreen`. So, we need the code for that component.

Comment: code has been added to my question

Comment: Oh, I see now. I think your problem is that in your test you are importing `TouchableOpacity` from your `HomeScreen` component. But most probably, what you are trying to import is the component from `react-native`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: when i do this I now get a new error 'Method "simulate" is meant to be run on 1 mode. 0 found instead'

Comment: Yes, that's probably because in your test you are rendering `TouchableOpacity` component and then you are searching for a `TouchableOpacity` inside. Is it possible that you want to render your `HomeScreen` component?

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You should import TouchableOpacity from 'react-native' in your test, then, try using "mount" (from the 'enzyme' package as well) instead of "shallow" to create your constant "button", that should do it.